# Exporting Products with their website specific attributes

Tags: magento2, tax, export

I have a product that has Tax Class "Taxable Goods" on one website A but has Tax Class "None" on a website B.  When I export it it comes out with 'tax_class_name' as 'Taxable Goods'.  I was expecting it to export both values, one for site A and the other for site B.
I think it is giving the site A value because it's the default value.  Is there any way to make it export both values?

Comment: If you didnt specify a filter you should get both values when exporting then just use excel to sort it

Comment: I am only getting one value even when I don't specify a filter.

Comment: I was told (offline) by a Magento Solutions Specialist that this is a bug/feature of Magento:  It does not export 'scoped values' (but it can import them).